# Does exist a way to redirect and show a javascript message?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, webforms, alert

After the user update a register I'd like to redirect him to another page and there I'd like to show a javascript message (alertfy.notify()) telling that the register was successfully updated.

I don't know if exists a way to write a script tag dynamically in the redirected page.

Please, I don't want to pass a variable in the querystring.

Comment: Pass a session value to the page you direct to. In the page load event of that page, check if that session variable is not null, if not, call the javascript alert.

Comment: Do you want to use javascript only? Or are you able to use a server-side language? If you only want to use javascript, you could make use of the local storage of the browser to store a flash-message. Or else you could manage a session on the server to store messages and show them to the user in the next response.

Comment: Simply include this at server when user logs in

Comment: I didn't use session because I think It could give me problems if the user is using more than one tab. At really I don't know if It is a bad practice to use session in this case and maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: You could use PreviousPage.FindControl() to check a value to determine whether or not it displays the alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, you could do for example:

```
<?php
session_start();

function storeMessage() {
    $_SESSION['message_registered'] = 'Your message...';
}

function getRegisterMessage() {
    return $_SESSION['message_registered'];
}
?>
```

And in javascript-only:

```
function setMessage(name, msg) {
    localStorage.setItem('message_' + name, msg);
}

function getMessage(name) {
    return localStorage.getItem('message_' + name, msg);
}

// at register form succesful submit
setMessage('registered', 'Thank you for creating an account!');

// at the page you want to get the message
var msg = getMessage('registered');
alert(msg);
```

You could also create something like a token in javascript. Every time when a tab opens with a page of your site, you create a token with javascript. Only the right tab with the right token gets the message. So the token is stored in the 'javascript memory' of each tab/window.

Comment: I didn't use session because I think It could give me problems if the user is using more than one tab.